# Python what container with constant size and constantly changing elements

Tags: python, performance, containers

Say I want a container to store some value returned from a sensor at 50Hz. I want store the present value, and also the last 100 so that I can say something about how the value is changing. What kind of container am I looking for? I was thinking maybe deque, and something like this:

```
def updateValue(data):
    self._value.append(data)
    self._value.popleft()
```

So every 20ms updateValue is called and appends an element on the end, and removes one from the start. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I realize now that if I define my deque to have a maxsize of 100 it will automatically call popleft() when I try to append more, seems as if this container fits me best!

Comment: consider writing that as a self-answer with the reasons why deque is a better choice than another option (e.g. rolling your own or etc)

Comment: For other ideas, google "circular buffer python".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is the correct container type.

I would pass in the optional `maxlen` argument so that the queue length is bound to 100:

> If `maxlen` is not specified or is `None`, deques may grow to an arbitrary
> length. Otherwise, the deque is bounded to the specified maximum
> length. **Once a bounded length deque is full, when new items are added,
> a corresponding number of items are discarded from the opposite end.**
> Bounded length deques provide functionality similar to the tail filter
> in Unix. **They are also useful for tracking transactions and other
> pools of data where only the most recent activity is of interest.**